# Routing jquery files with Mansonry

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Working on my little rails app, utilizing mansonry. It works, but I get bunch of 404 errors in the console. I think I'm routing them correctly, but the errors are there.

I might be routing it both correctly and incorrectly, but I can't find where.
I have these files in app > assets > javascripts

Here is code from my index page:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/utils.js"></script>
```

Here is an error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/path/to/jquery.masonry.min.js
```

Where or how can I locate if I'm routing the files incorrectly.

Thanks

Comment: You need to find out the path to your masonry file. Is it possible that it is in the same directory that the jQuery core is?

Comment: have you put all the js file in different locations? **jQuery in js** folder **masonry at root** and **utils at js folder**.

Answer (score 0):

js files in /app/assets/javascripts can be accessed via /assets/my.js  however you might check out the relevant view helper methods and read up on the rails 3 asset pipeline

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html